# Mostrar Submenu y ocultar cuando se hace click en otro Submenu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy intentando mostrar un **submenu** cuando se hace `click` en un item y que cuando le de `click` a otro **Submenu** este se debe ocultar y mostrar el **Submenu** del item que di `click` y ademas de eso debe eliminar las clase que se agrega llamada **open** y añadirla al item que di **click**, de igual manera si le doy `click` a un item y le vuelvo a dar `click` a ese mismo item, debe ocultar el **submenu**, pero no he podido lograrlo, tengo el siguiente código

```js
 $(".subtitle .action").click(function(event){
    var subtitle = $(this).parents(".subtitle");
    var submenu = $(subtitle).find(".submenu");
    
    $(".submenu").not($(submenu)).slideUp("slow").addClass("opacity");
    $(".open").not($(subtitle)).removeClass("open");

    $(subtitle).toggleClass("open");
    $(submenu).slideToggle("slow").toggleClass("opacity");

    return false;
   });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  .submenu {
   display: none;
  }
  .opacity {
   opacity: 0;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
  <li class="subtitle">
   <a href="#" class="action">Inicio</a>
   <ul class="submenu">
    <li>
     <a href="#">Inicio 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Inicio 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Inicio 3</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="subtitle">
   <a href="#" class="action">Nosotros</a>
   <ul class="submenu opacity">
    <li>
     <a href="#">Nosotros 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Nosotros 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Nosotros 3</a>
    </li>
   </ul>

  </li>
  <li class="subtitle">
   <a href="#" class="action">Contacto</a>
   <ul class="submenu opacity">
    <li>
     <a href="#">Contacto 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Contacto 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Contacto 3</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="subtitle">
   <a href="#" class="action">Empresa</a>
   <ul class="submenu opacity">
    <li>
     <a href="#">Empresa 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Empresa 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Empresa 3</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que haría yo es eliminar las clases a todos los elementos al momento de dar clic en un botón del menú, exceptuando los elementos que pertenecen al botón que ejecuta el evento osea a `this`.

```js
$(".subtitle .action").click(function(event){
 var subtitle = $(this).parents(".subtitle");
 var submenu = $(subtitle).find(".submenu");
 
 $(".submenu").not($(submenu)).slideUp("slow").removeClass("opacity");
 $(".open").not($(subtitle)).removeClass("open");

 $(subtitle).toggleClass("open");
 $(submenu).slideToggle("slow").toggleClass("opacity");

 return false;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  .submenu {
   display: none;
  }
  .opacity {
   opacity: 0.5;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
  <li class="subtitle">
   <a href="#" class="action">Inicio</a>
   <ul class="submenu">
    <li>
     <a href="#">Inicio 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Inicio 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Inicio 3</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="subtitle">
   <a href="#" class="action">Nosotros</a>
   <ul class="submenu">
    <li>
     <a href="#">Nosotros 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Nosotros 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Nosotros 3</a>
    </li>
   </ul>

  </li>
  <li class="subtitle">
   <a href="#" class="action">Contacto</a>
   <ul class="submenu">
    <li>
     <a href="#">Contacto 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Contacto 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Contacto 3</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="subtitle">
   <a href="#" class="action">Empresa</a>
   <ul class="submenu">
    <li>
     <a href="#">Empresa 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Empresa 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Empresa 3</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```